# Rendering HTML inside a DataList

Tags: html, formatting, datalist

I have a formatted text that contains Bolded, italicsed, and other styles implemented inside the message. I have this message stored in a Database. Now I want to implement these tags into work inside the a field inside the DataList. How do I do it?

Doesn't work. It just shows up the tags as such. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your "message" contains formatted HTML, you should simply HTMLDecode it after the DataBinder has evaluated the value of the "message" property. For example:

```
' "message" contains the string "<b>Hello World!</b>"
' Within the DataList:
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("message").ToString()) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: lol, np. You can vote up answers that you think have merit. You can also vote up answers that you have accepted. Thanks for accepting!  :-)